Can I suppress an error I'm getting with an older node module not compatible with Angular Ivy?
I'm using angular2-wizard but it's not compatible with Angular Ivy.
Is there a way to suppress the error so that I can keep on using it?
If I have to I can go into the library and hard code something if needed, I just wouldn't know where to start looking to do something like that. If I can get it to run without the errors, I think I might have enough knowledge to go in and make the appropriate changes.
Error when running:

'FormWizardModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class. This likely means that the library (angular2-wizard) which declares FormWizardModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.


You could try to clone the source repo, and upgrade from Angular 2.3.1 (!) to your version of Angular. There doesn't look like there's anything in the package that would prevent an upgrade. There's no way to use ViewEngine code with an Ivy project, though. Backwards compatibility (NGCC) was removed in Angular 16.

There are only two components in the package, so it might be easier to copy them into your project (with the appropriate license notices) rather than using the actual NPM package.

How would I go about doing something like that? I can see in the repo there is wizard-step and and wizard.component but where would I begin to know which files are needed, how to copy them into my project and then most importantly how to use them?

You'll want the wizard.component.ts and wizard-step.component.ts files. The .spec.ts files are test files so it's up to you and your testing strategy if you want those. If you look at the import {...} from '...'; statements at the top of the .ts files, you can determine which dependencies to include when copying the files. There are none in this case (except that the components use CSS classes from Bootstrap - you'll need to install Bootstrap for those to work properly).

Otherwise, they're just components. Use them the same way you'd use components you created in your project. Import them into an @NgModule or standalone @Component and then use their selectors in the template of the component you want to use as a parent.

thanks I think I figured it out and have it working now without the node package!
